# Switch Bubble Sort from Increasing to decreasing

Tags: java, sorting

I need to switch from increasing to decreasing. Here is what I have:

```java
public static void bubbleSort(double[] array) {
    boolean swapping = true;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length && swapping; i++) {
        // array is already sorted if no swapping happened in the previous inner loop
        swapping = false; // assume no swapping, before entering the inner loop
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {      
                double temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;

                swapping = true;
            }
        } 
    }
    printArray(array);
}
```

Comment: just swap greater than (>) to less than (<) in your if statement

Comment: in the beginning for loop?